# ios TableviewCell recalculate height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tabviewcell and I want to set a label text (subview of tableviewcell) dynamically.But when I set it labels heigh show 0 (not seen in screen).My code is below but when I set text it does no recalculate heigh.What is the problem here?

```
protocol EarningsSemisecureViewDelegate : class {
    func enterButtonTapped()
}

class EarningsSemisecureViewCell : UITableViewCell {

    var noDataText : String? {
        didSet(newValue) {
            noDataLabel.text = newValue?.localized()
        }
    }
    private var noDataLabel = RadxLabel()
    weak var delegate: EarningsSemisecureViewDelegate?

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        customizeView()
     }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        customizeView()
    }

    private func customizeView() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
        noDataLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        noDataLabel.textAlignment = .center
        noDataLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(noDataLabel)
        noDataLabel.leading = self.contentView.leading + 10
        noDataLabel.trailing = self.contentView.trailing - 10
        noDataLabel.top = self.contentView.top + 20

        let button = WalletButton()
        button.setTitle("login.button.enter".localized(), for: .normal)
        button.styleNo = 1
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTapGestureRecognizer {[weak self] in
        if let semiSecureViewDelegate = self?.delegate {
            semiSecureViewDelegate.enterButtonTapped()
        }
    }
    self.contentView.addSubview(button)
    button.top = noDataLabel.bottom + 30
    button.trailing = self.contentView.trailing - 10
    button.leading = self.contentView.leading + 10
    }
}



let semisecureViewCell = EarningsSemisecureViewCell()
        semisecureViewCell.noDataText = "earnings.not.login.info"
        return semisecureViewCell
```

cell is returning in tableviewdatasource.

Comment: Have you tried `noDataLabel.sizeToFit()` after you have set the new text value?

Comment: where I must add it?  in didSet?

Comment: Yes. After you set `noDataLabel.text = newValue?.localized()`. UILabel will set its own size depending on its `text` property. As long as `RadxLabel` is a subclass of `UILabel`...

Comment: yes I dit it but nothing changed

Comment: Is the `contentView` of your cell sized properly? Constraints for `contentView` are missing, so your label constraints are not working.

Comment: I found mu problem.Problem is newValue is nil because of I used it in didSet.I must use it in setter

Comment: Right. in `didSet`, `noDataText` already contains the new value.... Use `noDataLabel.text = noDataText?.localized()` in `didSet` ;)

Comment: or I can use willSet function to use newvalue  both of them  usefull.Thank you @Rainer Schwarz

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :]